# iptables configuration CIDR notation

Tags: iptables, ip, firewall

```
WINPE1 = 192.168.10.5
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.5 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.5 -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

I wrote these rules in response to these guidelines:

- Only allow HTTPD traffic from WINPE1. Use an ACCEPT command. We are implementing a DROP policy.
- Allow Ping traffic from WINPE1 only. Again, use an ACCEPT command.

However, in the guidelines it is stated that subnet addressing (like 192.160.10.0/24 for example) must be used throughout the firewall; no individual IP addresses allowed for source machines and no specified ranges allowed either e.g., `--src-range 192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200`.

How do I change the 192.168.10.5 address to CIDR notation without granting access to other IP addresses?

Comment: I've never seen `192.160.10.0\24` used, why the backslash instead of a forward slash?

Answer (score 3):

iptables is able to handle networks realy easy.
In your case:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.10.0/24 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.10.0/24 -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

Or instead of `192.168.10.0/24` you can use `192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0`